# How to pass multiple arrays/variables into DOMPDF in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, pdf, dompdf, loadview

I try to pass multiple variables, an arrays and a single variable. This is what I code:

```
tanggal_arsips  = $req->tanggal_arsip;
$nama_file  = "Laporan Pengarsipan[".$tanggal_arsips."].pdf";

$antrian    = DB::table("antrian_sp AS a")
                      ->select(array("a.tanggal as tanggal","a.noper as noper","a.nama as nama","b.nomor_paspor as nomor_paspor"))
                      ->join("data_pemohon AS b", "a.noper", "=", "b.noper")
                      ->join("arsip AS c", "a.noper", "=", "c.noper")
                      ->where("a.keterangan", "=", "1")
                      ->where("c.status_arsip", "=", "arsip")
                      ->whereDate("c.tanggal_arsip","=",$tanggal_arsips)
                      ->get();

$pdf    = PDF::loadView('coba',['antrian'=>$antrian, 'tanggal_arsips'=>$tanggal_arsips]);
return $pdf->download($nama_file);
```

And I try to print the"tanggal_arsips" variable in the view, this is the code:

```
echo($tanggal_arsips)
```

The problem is I can't print variable "tanggal_arsips", it shows nothing. What is the problem?, help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: you're missing the dollar sign `$` on tanggal_arsips. First line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass variables like below

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', compact('factuur', 'factuurregels', 'totaalprijs'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If there was error, what was the error message?
If there was no error, when you print $tanggal_arsips before loading PDF view, does it show anything?